# Is it possible to localize ArcGIS Feature-Classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, feature-class, internationalization

I wondered if it is possible to translate an ArcGIS feature-class into different languages?

For example I want to translate the Fields of the class and then add the data for the defined languages. I was not able to find any information about this on the ESRI sites. Anyone can tell me if it is even possible an when how to achive multilanguage feature-classes?

**UPDATE**

Let me give you a short usage example:

I have a Website and want to use data from an arcgis server that is stored in a feature database. Now, the webpage is in english and german. If the user watches the site in english the attribute names of the features should be displayed in english. If the user is german, it should show the german localized names. Maybe a feature has an attribut-field called "address". In the english version the text should be "Address" and in the german one "Adresse"

Comment: ArcGIS INSPIRE http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgis_inspire/1.0/help/index.html#/Release_Notes/014m00000085000000/

Comment: On the database side, this SO question covers 3 schema design possibilities: [Schema for a multilanguage database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316780/386205). Could you elaborate more on what you need multiple language support for, and how you would use it?

Comment: Hi blah238, I modified my Question and added an usage example

Answer (score 1):

[X-Ray for ArcCatalog](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c181d52a95b946abab6208322dc8410b) allows easy localization of feature classes, descriptions, and field names.

[image]

It allows you to edit most of the information for datasets, feature classes and some associated metadata, as well as a host of other features.  The editing can be accomplished in excel, making editing or keeping track of different localizations easier.  Edits done in excel get pushed back to the databases XML document, which then can be pushed back to the database.

[image]

There is also an [X-Ray for ArcMap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=596204091a9147f9b609a6537a51d0d1) that allows the same functionality for map documents, with the ability to edit layer names and descriptions.

Comment: "Easy" and "localization" in the same sentence is a pretty big claim. Can you describe how it works, and what work the user needs to perform?